# Urdu Font Formatting issue

Tags: java, android, arabic

Hi  I have rendered some **Arabic** language text in android ListView .
it is not displaying the language correctly . It inserts a space after
each language character . below is the snap shot  I want to know how to
fix this language issue

help is appreciated .

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell us the way you use to display Urdu language? I just wanted to clarify that you have created the specified value folder under res folder

Comment: i have parsed an xml which is giving me the urdu in correct format it goes wrong   after rendering to listview.

Comment: facing same problem, what is the solution?

Comment: this is already fixes in operations systems after ginger bread

Answer (score -2):

This is the Bug of the Android Emulator.But it works perfectly on device.i guess you need to install some widget or any thing else to see the language that you on emulator.as far device concern it work perfectly on my samsung duos!!